# Css Circle image with sticker corner

Tags: css, responsive

[image: Css Image Circle with sticker]

I want to make css corder with sticker corner like this (responsive). Please help me ! Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I made that :

```
<div style="width:100%;height:500px;position:relative;">
  <img style="position:absolute;width:20%;left:50%;" class='rd100' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg/2000px-Circle_-_black_simple.svg.png" />
  <img class='rd100' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg/2000px-Circle_-_black_simple.svg.png" />
</div>
```

and the css :

```
img.rd100
{
    width:100%;height: auto;
}
```

here a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kgcd4dLn/3/

You just have to add other circle for other stickers.

Good Luck :)

Comment: look again at my fiddle I forgot to upload the right version